# Avoid creating temporary table when both group by and order by are used in query

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, sql-order-by, temp-tables

Is there any way to avoid creation of temporary table in such a query?

```
SELECT item_id FROM titem
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY item_created;
```

I tried to create indexes `(item_id, item_created)` and `(item_created, item_id)`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with your query. When the group by is performed which item_created is selected for each group? MySQL by default will select one for each group more or less randomly (from within the group). As only one item_created is used for each group a temporary table is required to sort it.

I would advise you to use one of the aggregation functions such as min() or max() to get a abetter defined item_created to sort on. This still won't fix teh temporary table problem, an index on item_id is about the best you can do.

```
SELECT item_id, max(item_created) as ic FROM titem
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY ic;
```

It is interesting to note that some databases eg Oracle (i'm told) would throw and error on your original query as item_created is neither in the selected fields in an aggregate function nor is it in the group by clause. MySQL can be set to mimic this behaviour.

Comment: item_created - is a denormalized field (from table items), so for one uniq_id, item_created would be the same.The reason I denormalized it was to use index for sorting. And it works perfectly, until I need to use group-by.

Comment: You may find this article interesting. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html